# How to pass Parameter NetSuite RESTLet using Advanced REST client

Tags: netsuite

[image]   How to pass Parameter NetSuite RESTLet using Advanced REST client. I Cant get parameter value.

```
function getRecord(datain)
{
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','recordtype='+datain.recordtype);
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','id='+datain.id);
    var sugu = nlapiLoadRecord(datain.recordtype, datain.id);

    return JSON.stringify(sugu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nhac.png)

You Need to pass the parameter in header not in variable .please refer that image

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually trying to send a GET request then it goes in the URL, as in the attached image.  If you are trying to send a POST or PUT, then you add it into the payload, though (that will show up once you select POST or PUT).

[image]